# Sqlite database update after async post not working

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

I am using an HttpPost method to send a message from an android device via a web server. When the response comes back, the device is supposed to update the on-board database with a format I've used a million times,

```
if(postMessage(theMessage).trim().equals("OK")){ 
  DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(ShareDialog.this);
  database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
  strSharedWith = strSharedWith + theNameEncoded+ "|~|";//my delimiter; 

  String strFilter = "listTitle= '" + listTitle + "'";
  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
  values.put("sharedWith", strSharedWith);
  int numRows = database.update("listdata", values, strFilter, null);
  database.close();
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), numRows + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//Toasts "1"
```

Everything appears to work: the message is sent to the other device, the response comes back from the web server, and the Toast message indicates that one row has been updated...but the value remains null. Anyone see what I'm missing? Thanks

Edit: I've found that the query works fine if moved ahead of calling the AsyncTask...seems strange to me that the query isn't executed, as I know that the if block is (because there's an else block that clearly is not executed). At the risk of embarrassing myself I'm posting the code for the AsyncTask; I know the use of

```
while (something.equals("")){
  try {
Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

is bad practice, but that was the way I got my post to the server to work. I now see that I'd better clean up my second thread usage, so if someone could do that (and show me where to update the local database), I'll mark it answered. Oh, side note: the advice to use execSQL generated exceptions because of improper escaping of my pipe delimiter--the format I'm using avoids that. OK, with red face:

```
if(postMessage(theNameEncoded).trim().equals("OK")){
   //was making my database update here, which didn't work
  m_adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
  loadAdapter();
  setListAdapter(m_adapter);
}else{
  //alert dialog
}

public String postMessage(String toWhom){
 //get stuff from database
  strToPost = (assembled from the database call);
  new MyAsyncTask().execute(strToPost);
  while (privateStatus.equals("")){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  if (privateStatus.indexOf("OK")>-1){
    //the return from the webserver, OK on success
    return "OK";
  }else{
    return "Not a friend";
  }
```

And, the asyncTask

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{
  protected void onPreExecute() {
   //progress dialog started
  }

protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.my-domain.com/list_post.php");
try {
       List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("listSent", strToPost));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fromUser", myName));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("toUser", sharingListWith));

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        status = httpclient.execute(httppost, new BasicResponseHandler());
        while (status.equals("")){
          try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
        setStatus(status);

        //exception catching

       protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
        pDialog.dismiss();
       }
      }


public String setStatus (String theStatus){
 if(!theStatus.equals(null)){
   privateStatus = theStatus;
    }
      return null;
  }
```

I know. And, two of those while{sleep} things. Any recommendations on how to properly incorporate a response from a webserver in a secondary thread would be appreciated.

Comment: Am investigating [this excellent android developer article](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html) regarding the topic; seems like the issue is addressed here. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: k dude i m going to delete my answer..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could only update the local database by calling the update function before calling the AsyncTask; I used ConnectivityManager (as explained in my link above) to prevent the update from occurring if the HttpPost wasn't going to happen. I consider this inadequate, and still don't understand why I couldn't use the onPostExecute section of asyncTask--which, being in the UI thread and being handed a result from the web server post, seemed like the place to do this. Still stumped, so if anyone can shed light on this I'd appreciate it. In the meantime, I'll mark this as answered as my app works!